# Delphi resource string optimization

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have written a class that is declared like this in the private section `piaces: TCompStar;` and I am using the following code on the form create event:

```
begin

 pieces.Items[0].insert('string 1');
 pieces.Items[0].insert('string 2');
 pieces.Items[0].insert('string 3');
 //I am adding other 12 elements

end;
```

This is under firemonkey. Now I have only 15 elements (just debug) but soon I could have (worst case) 12509 items. We have a delphi unit that contains all the strings that must be added with the `insert(const pieceDesrc: string);`. We need the pieces to be written in english and german (then worst case is 12509*2) so we have a lot of strings.

I have read about `resourcestring` and I have seen that they are optimized strings that are good for localization. Also there are a few topics on stack overflow about them.

---

We care about the optimization because we want to be able to load 25018 strings quickly when the form creates. My question is: does it makes sense if we created a unit containing only resourcestrings and then we add them to the class? Like:

```
resourcestring
 str1 = 'text';
 str2 = 'text';
 str3 = 'text';

 pieces.Items[0].insert(str1);
 pieces.Items[0].insert(str2);
 pieces.Items[0].insert(str3);
```

Or it's better if I use the approach you see in the first block above?

Comment: Store them in an external file. Don't bloat the executable with them. So much easier to manage too.

Comment: Doesn't the resourcestring use an external file in fact? Or you are suggesting me to do a txt file and load it with something like a stringlist?

Comment: `Resourcestring` does not use an external file, it stores the string in the executable as, well, a resource. Hence the name of the keyword.

Comment: I suggest that you use ressource from JSON file, i think that is better and more flexible.

Comment: @BMS, what is the advantage of using JSON against the existing Delphi resource file system except another "dependency" and a complete implementation for every control?

Comment: A `resourcestring` is stored in the executable as a resource (thus the name). Why do you need to load 25K strings all at once in the first place? That's a huge amount of wasted memory, when you can't possibly display 25K strings simultaneously; if you need that many strings and need to look them up quickly for some reason, use a database. If you're doing it just for internationalization (English and German language support), there are built-in mechanisms for doing that without manually loading strings.

Comment: So at the end what? Should I create a txt file with the strings and load it with the resource manager? I really need my apk to support the 2 languages efficiently

Comment: There is no one optimal way of doing it. There are lots of ideas and it depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve. Resource files are stored as separate files but compiled into the executable, the idea being that you would have an 'English' and a 'German' resource file and compile them separately. A lot of people don't find this very satisfactory and prefer something like a TDictionary (although there are many equivalent approaches, including a database as mentioned above). You pays your money and takes your choice.