# Delphi resources and resourcestrings optimization

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

From a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422811/delphi-resource-string-optimization) I had posted some time ago I have understood that a good way to import 25k strings at runtime is using external files. If I created 25k strings at compile time I will increase too much the size of my andorid/iOS app.

I have read in the documentation about [`resources`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Resources) and I have implemented them in my application. I have some text files (containing a lot of strings inside, about 13k each) loaded through *Project > Resources and Images*.

From what I have understood an *.rc file is generated and the resources will be linked together with my apk/exe/whatever. Does this really advantage me? To be more specific:

- Resources. I have to load them calling for example `Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream()`
- No resources. I initialize a lot of `resourcestrings` in a separated unit of my program and they will be compiled

I care about the file size and also I need to load them as fast as possible. In both cases I guess that the file size will increase but are resources "faster" than resourcestrings? I hope you can understand what I mean.

**Note**. I am using Firemonkey so I cannot use the Translation Manager given by the IDE since it's only for Win32.

Comment: `resourcestring` is being read from a resource file, so sorry, I can't understand your question.

Comment: `Resourcestrings` *are* resources, just resources that you can define in your source code, instead of in a separate file. The end product is the same.

Comment: Should I declare an entire unit of resourcestrings or should I create a txt file and load it as resource?

Comment: In the question I have linked above people suggested me to use separated files and load them via resources because resourcestrings would bloat my app size too much...

Comment: @Emma: Do whatever you find more convenient. The text file may be easier to edit by someone else. If you compile that text file to a resource anyway, then there is no difference with resourcestrings.

Comment: Resourcestrings would bloat your source code too much. You would have huge units. Since this is for localization/internalization purposes, did you look at localization in a different way too? See the online help or DocWiki: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Internationalization_and_Localization

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Ok so it's basically the same, thank you :) In this case I will consider to use a unit having only resourcestrings. Just out of curiosity, if I declared them as strings (and NOT resourcestrings) will the file size increase?

Comment: I am under firemonkey. I will look at that link many thanks

Comment: The advantege of resource strings is that they can be edited in the compiled executable, i.e. there is no need to recompile it. Just use a resource editor to modif the resources. This makes it pretty easy to produce several different language versions of the same application. The person doing the translation does not need Delphi, just knowledge of the language and of the program.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Declared_Constants#Resource_Strings

Comment: @RudyVelthuis is it possible to load resourcestrings via a TResourceStream?

Comment: @Emma: yes, of course.

Comment: @EmmaRossignoli: yes, but not easily. You would have to manually parse the entire stringtable resource to extract what you need. `LoadResString()` is a cleaner API for that, and `resourcestring` is a nice language-level wrapper for that.

Comment: Both your methods use resources. They're just accessed slightly differently. There will be no meaningful difference in file size. Have you identified loading resources as a performance bottleneck in your app using a profiler? If not, then you're engaging in what is known as *premature optimization*, which is wasting time trying to speed up code that you have not identified as actually being slow. It's typically a vast waste of time that could be better spent doing something actually productive.

Comment: Keep them in separate files so that you can have one executable rather than one for each language.